# How do I run a regression with an interaction but with only the data from one category in the variable?

Tags: r, regression, subset

I'm trying to run a multivariate regression with an interaction term but I only want to use data from the treatment group.

To be more specific: I'm looking at the effect of treatment on knowledge acquisition, with trust as an interaction. I have multiple trust variables which correspond to which treatment condition people were exposed to and so e.g. I want my 'trust in social media' variable to interact with data from only the treatment (people who were exposed to a social media source) group. On the other hand, I have a 'trust in traditional news' variable and I want to interact that only with data from the control (traditional news source) group.

I tried to subset the data to specify the treatment group and then use this in the "data = " argument in my regression.

```
treatment_subset2 <- subset(maindata, treatment_dummy == "2")
model.trust <- lm(treatment_dummy ~ knowledgeindex * trust_smR, 
                  data = treatment_subset2)
summary(model.trust)
```

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear on what you want to do, but current version doesn't make sense. You subsetted your data to a single value of `treatment_dummy`, then used `treatment_dummy` as a *response variable*. Are you sure you didn't mean to write `knowledgeindex ~ treatment_dummy * trust_smR` ? (It still won't work, but it would be good to get any extraneous sources of confusion out of the way.)  This may be a [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) question - I think your question doesn't make sense, and explaining why may be a stats rather than a programming issue

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely sure how to go about it but I want to only run a regression with trust as an interaction using one category of the treatment_dummy variable (it is split into either 1 for control or 2 for treatment).

Comment: As @BenBolker said, that doesn't make much sense from a theoretical statistical standpoint.

Now, maybe it doesn't work for you, because the treatment dummy might be numerc. Thus, it would have to look like this: ```subset(maindata, treatment_dummy == 2)```

Also, you could use tidyverse in the lm functions: 
```model.trust <- lm(treatment_dummy ~ knowledgeindex * trust_smR, 
                  data = maindata %>% filter(treatmentdummy== 2))```